How to resolve Content Security Policy issue in chrome extension
I loaded facebook-sdk in my chrome extension to login with facebook account.
This is error in chrome extension browser when load facebook sdk
This is my code & I use manifest v3
manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "My Calendly Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  // more detail...
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": ["script.js"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ]
}

login
import React from 'react';
...
import FacebookLogin from "react-facebook-login";


const Login = ({ onLogin, onCancel }) => {
  const onFinish = async (values) => {
    // Login action
  };

  const handleFacebookResponse = (response) => {
    if (response.status === "unknown" || response.error) {
      notification.error({
        message: 'Login Failed',
        description: 'Invalid credentials. Please check your Facebook account.',
      });
    } else {
      onLogin(response);
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response));
      localStorage.setItem('token', 'dummy-token'); // Replace with actual token logic if needed
    }
  };

  return (
    <Card style={{ width: 400, margin: 'auto' }}>
        // General Login Form
        <div style={{ alignItems: 'center', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <FacebookLogin
            appId="1082534248908784"
            fields="name,email,picture"
            callback={handleFacebookResponse}
            textButton="Login with Facebook"
          />
        </div>
      </Form>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Login;


I can see the facebook sdk dialog.

Do it inside the sandboxed iframe.
